The updated value is not visible in the state and the component is not re-rendering
When I click the "delivered" button, the state of newQunatity doesn't update immediately. But after reloading the page, it updates the state of newQuantity. How will I update the state of newQuantity immediately?
// SingleBook.jsx

const loadedBook = useLoaderData();
    // console.log(loadedBook);
    const { _id, name, image, description, price, quantity, supplier, sold } = loadedBook;
    const [newQuantity, setNewQuantity] = useState(quantity);

    const handleDelivered = (_id) => {

        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/books/${_id}/delivered`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            // body: JSON.stringify({})
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setNewQuantity(newQuantity - 1);
                console.log("The value of newQuantity:", newQuantity);
            })
    }

    // Use useEffect to log newQuantity whenever it changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Updated newQuantity:", newQuantity);
    }, [newQuantity]);


 <div className="card-actions justify-end">
                        <button onClick={() => handleDelivered(_id)} className="btn btn-primary">Delivered</button>
                    </div>

